# Почему sum() в Pandas выдает int, а не float при подсчете булевых значений

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в некотором видео у лектора при подсчете строк с булевыми значениями получается число типа флоат, у меня получается целое число. В чем может быть причина? вроде все так же делаю, за исключением rename[image: Это у лектора]

[image: Это мой код]

Comment: Потому что 1 - правда, 0 - ложь, флоат тут никак получиться не может

Comment: Спасибо, вот я тоже так рассуждаю, однако лектор получил флоат каким то образом) Для меня загадка

Comment: У меня было предположение, что наличие `NA` может как-то влиять, но я проверил - гипотеза не подтвердилась. Надо смотреть исходные данные, так непонятно в чём может быть дело.

Comment: У меня такое получилось сделать только если в `success` лежат не булевы значения, а `0`, `1` и `np.nan`, в этом случае столбец будет иметь тип `float`, как известно. С `True`, `False` и `np.nan` такой фокус не пройдёт, столбец будет типа `object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое возможно только если в `success` лежат не прямо вот питоновские булевы значения `True` и `False`, а их целые значения `0`, `1` и ещё в столбце есть `np.nan`, в этом случае столбец будет иметь тип `float`, как известно (в широко используемых версиях `Pandas` `NA` есть только в типах `float`, а в `int` нет `NA`), и суммироваться он будет тоже в `float`. С `True`, `False` и `np.nan` такой фокус не пройдёт, столбец тогда будет типа `object` и результат суммирования будет преобразован в `int`.

Пример:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'client': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'success': [1, 0, 1, np.nan]})
df.groupby('client', as_index=False).sum()
```

|  | client | success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1.0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1.0 |